# what's a homogeneous transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Minkowski writes in his paper on Time and Space:

> If, for simplicity, we retain the same zero point of space and time, the first-mentioned group signifies in mechanics that we may subject the axes of x,y,z at t = 0 to any rotation we choose about the origin, corresponding to the homogeneous linear transformations of the expression
>   $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2$$

I've done a Google search on "homogeneous transformation", which has only returned results that give examples such as rotation, scaling etc. What's its general defintion?

Comment: Homogeneous transformation between what spaces? With what structure?

Comment: Depends on the context. What do you need?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function

Comment: @PeterFranek I've edited in the context of the question

Comment: Homogeneity usually refers to the how the function / transformation interacts with scalar multiples.  i.e. $T(\lambda x) = f(\lambda)T(x)$, for vectors $x$ and scalars $\lambda$.